# Include file as a string in Dart

Tags: dart

In Dart is there a way to include a file as a string, similar to Rust's [`include_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html) macro?

I do not want to load the string at runtime from a file or asset.

Comment: No, there is no built-in way to do that.  Can you explain what you're ultimately trying to accomplish (this seems like an XY problem) and why loading the string at runtime would be unsuitable?  Otherwise you could use code-generation to generate `.dart` source files.

Comment: It's not an XY problem. This is a common thing to want to do (hence the Rust function!) so I'm not sure why you would assume it is. It's usually used to embed files like GPU shaders or maybe HTML templates. You *can* do it at runtime but it's simpler and more reliably (and infinitesimally faster!) to embed the content in the binary. I'll probably just do it at runtime instead though given that Dart doesn't make this easy (and there are definitely downsides to allowing it).

Comment: It's not *that* common a thing to do (hence *most* languages don't directly support it).  While there certainly would be useful, based on what *specifically* you want to do, there might be simpler or alternative ways to do it.

Comment: Answer was deleted due to silly SO rules but: There is a package called Aspen that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Not with a similar function.

However there is a workaround that I sometimes use which is a bit different from what you are looking for but might suit your needs :

File `translated.dart` (presumably generated) :

```dart
const translatedHelloWorld = "Hola mundo\n";
```

In your main file :

```dart
import 'translated.dart';

void main() {
  assert(translatedHelloWorld, "Hola mundo\n");
}
```